# How do I conditionally restrict a payload in a FOR EACH scope's collection expression in Mulesoft 4?

Tags: xml, foreach, conditional-statements, dataweave, mulesoft

I've been given the following XML in my payload.

```
<colors>
   <color>
      <name>red</name>
      <type>primary</type>
   </color>
   <color>
      <name>orange</name>
      <type>secondary</type>
   </color>
   <color>
      <name>blue</name>
      <type>primary</type>
   </color>
   <color>
      <name>green</name>
      <type>secondary</type>
   </color>
</colors>
```

I want only "primary" types to be processed in a `FOREACH`.  In Mulesoft 3.x, the collection could be restricted with an `XPATH3` function.

```
<foreach 
   collection="#[xpath3('//colors/color[type/text()=\'primary\']', payload, 'NODESET')]" 
   doc:name="For each primary color">
      <... other commands .../>
</foreach>
```

In Mulesoft 4, how do I structure a `FOR EACH` to conditionalize the collection by type?  It uses DataWeave 2.0 syntax for the expression, but I couldn't find any examples of whittling down a collection.  I don't think I need `XPATH` anymore because the payload should be addressable with dot notation, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following to get just the colors where type is primary:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    colors: 
          color: payload.colors.*color filter ($.`type` == "primary") map
          {
              a:$.name
          }.a
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<colors>
  <color>red</color>
  <color>blue</color>
</colors>
```

Or the following to get a little more than just the colors:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
{
    colors: 
          color: payload.colors.*color filter ($.`type` == "primary")
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<colors>
  <color>
    <name>red</name>
    <type>primary</type>
  </color>
  <color>
    <name>blue</name>
    <type>primary</type>
  </color>
</colors>
```

Comment: Once you have the payload ready in there , you can configure in your for-each collection  `payload.colors` (so that it gets an array of color elements)..

Comment: You might want to output application/java here to avoid to parsing the XML again in the foreach.

Comment: Is this in lieu of using a dataweave expression for the collection?  Are you saying preface the `For Each` with another separate transform first?

Comment: You can do it inline (i.e. within the For Each collection defintion using the same concept or preface the For Each .. Choice is yours to make!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a DW script within the foreach **`collection`** instead of using XPATH.

Example For Each: ***(Assuming the input payload is an XML type)***

```
<foreach doc:name="For each primary color" collection="#[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload..*color[?($.'type' == 'primary')]]">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Just logging" message="#[payload]"/>
</foreach>
```

If only name as an output in the collection: ***(Add .name)***

```
<foreach doc:name="For each primary color" collection="#[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload..*color[?($.'type' == 'primary')].name]">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Just logging" message="#[payload]"/>
</foreach>
```